# Fewest LEGO sets to get all the new Avengers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron, lego

Back when *Avengers* came out, there were related LEGO sets released.  I picked up as few as possible to get all of the Avengers minifigs.  With *Avengers: Age of Ultron* out, LEGO's released a bunch of new LEGO sets related to the new film.  However, they split up the characters across various sets, so there's no trivial way to buy the entire team.  I'd like to pick up the fewest number of sets to get the minifigs for the new Avengers.  Based on the trailers, that means 3 characters: Scarlet Witch, Quicksilver, and Vision.

What's the fewest number of LEGO sets I need to purchase to get the new Avengers minifigs?

Comment: I shared your question & expect an informed response fairly soon.

Comment: Not to belittle this SE, but maybe http://bricks.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit?

Comment: Why don't you just buy the minifigs individually from eBay?

Comment: @systemdown - Yes, I agree. It's not off-topic here, but it would be a much better fit there.

Comment: @Richard Because of a terrible markup! Vision, for instance, is running ~$13 USD on [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?pg=1&q=vision&sz=10&searchSort=P), for a set that's only $80. So, you're paying 16%+ the cost of the whole set in that case. If you've got the time, you're much better off buying the whole set and then reselling the bricks and minifigs you don't want. The non-Vision minifigs alone in the Vision set could net ~$35.

Comment: @CreationEdge - So, it would be a lot cheaper to buy them singly, but you don't perceive this as good value because you don't get the sets.

Comment: @Richard No, I meant I don't see it as a good value because you're only saving money upfront. If you have the capital and patience, you can spend more upfront and then sell *all* of the extra pieces to save more. For some sets you can actually make a profit, depending on how you piece it out and how long you're willing to wait.

Comment: I maybe misunderstand the question but the fact that they are Avengers figs doesn't really matter, no? If I am right, it could be a better fit for Maths.SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My sources tell me that it looks like you'll need 5 out of the 6 total Ultron sets to get the new characters;

1. **Quicksilver**: [Hydra Fortress Smash](http://brickset.com/sets/76041-1/The-Hydra-Fortress-Smash)
2. **Vision** & Ultimate Ultron: [Quinjet City Chase](http://brickset.com/sets/76032-1/The-Avengers-Quinjet-City-Chase)
3. **Scarlet Witch** & Ultron Prime: [The Hulk Buster Smash](http://brickset.com/sets/76031-1/The-Hulk-Buster-Smash)
4. Ultron MK1 & Iron Legion: [Attack on Avengers Tower](http://brickset.com/sets/76038-1/Attack-on-Avengers-Tower)
5. Ultron Sentry's (both variants) & Iron Man MK45: [Iron Man Vs. Ultron](http://brickset.com/sets/76029-1/Iron-Man-vs-Ultron)
6. If you want the Hawkeye from the Helicarrier: [Hydra Showdown](http://brickset.com/sets/76030-1/Avengers-Hydra-Showdown)

The top 3 will get you the new avengers, the remainder will get you all of the Age of Ultron variants.

Comment: I *think* the OP meant only the new Avengers **heroes**, which would mean 3 sets: 76041, 76032, 76031. Alternatively, since the Quicksilver set so so *godawful*, you should just not buy it and opt to get the minifig separate, if you so desire.

Comment: I would add that Hulk Buster Smash and Hydra Fortress Smash both come with a new variant of Hulk, that has darker green coloring and spiky hair more in line with the movie depiction.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save yourself around $200 you can buy them individually from a  [Lego minifig store](http://www.theminifigurestore.co.uk/?s=ultron&post_type=product) or from [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?q=quicksilver).

[image]

Comment: There is **no** official minifig store. The only official web store for LEGO is http://www.shop.lego.com/. Additionally, The LEGO Company, due to licensing agreements, can't sell *any* licensed minifigs individually, as it's been ruled that qualifies as selling "action figures", which other companies have the license to sell for those brands, but LEGO does not. If you want the figures separately, you have to buy through a third party.

Comment: @creationedge - Cheerfully edited

Comment: I used to work customer service for LEGO, so I'm picky about some stuff.

Comment: @CreationEdge - It won't please you to know that I used to buy the minifig keyrings for £5, pull out the keyring and sell them for a tenner on ebay then...

Comment: Works for me. They used to sell the magnets with the figures detachable, but Hasbro threw a fit so now they are fused to the magnet. I think they should be able to sell them, but it's the *other* companies legal tantrums that make the decision.